# How to flip 2D sprite when you move mouse cursor from Left to Right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am attempting to make 2D topdown shooter game. I first implemented weapon rotation and it worked fine. However, after implementing character sprite flip, the weapon sprite now doesn't rotate to right and the character sprite went weird. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Sorry for quality of the Gif.]

**Character Movement Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 movement;
    bool facingRight = true;

     // Update is called once per frame
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {      
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (mousePos.x > transform.position.x && facingRight)
        {
            flip();
        }
        else if (mousePos.x > transform.position.x && !facingRight)
        {
            flip();
        }
    }

    void flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movement.Normalize();
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movement.x * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, movement.y * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

**Weapon Rotation Script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GunRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Gun Rotation Function
    public float offset;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRender;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Gun Rotation Function
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);

        if (rotZ < 89 && rotZ > -89)
        {
            Debug.Log("Facing right");
            spriteRender.flipY = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Facing left");
            spriteRender.flipY = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Double check your `if` conditions for when you `flip()`. When your mouse is to the right side of your sprite, it will keep toggling `flip()` since they both have the same `mousePos.x > transform.position.x` condition. You don't need to be checking for `facingRight` at all in this condition since only the relative positions of your sprite and mouse matter.

Comment: Why do you rotate the player? Why not take the same route and rather flip only the sprite? And then rather mirror the `movement` vector accordingly

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for the comment. I did this way by following youtube tutorial video since I had no idead how to implemnt such function. If your idea is better, then Id love to do so. But since i am not at level where i can understand your idea, could you please teach me how to implement your idea please.

Answer (score 2):

You need just to reverse > in else if condition and it'll work fine

```
Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

    if (mousePos.x > transform.position.x && !facingRight)
    {
        flip();
    }
    else if (mousePos.x < transform.position.x && facingRight)
    {
        flip();
    }
```